# Could not find module `Control.Monad.Reader'

Tags: haskell

Today when I tried to compile my code in Geany I got this error

```
Could not find module `Control.Monad.Reader':
  it was found in multiple packages: monads-fd-0.1.0.1 mtl-1.1.0.2
Compilation failed.
```

I get the same for the Writer monad; I thought I should remove one of those packages, but I do not want to break other packages, so now what should I do, yesterday everything worked without any problem.

Comment: I found it, it's [right here](http://themonadreader.wordpress.com/)! Oh wait, that's not what you meant...

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you have recently installed `monads-fd`, perhaps as a dependency of something else you installed.  Both `monads-fd` and `mtl` packages contain the module `Control.Monad.Reader`, so GHC doesn't know which one to use when you compile some code that imports it.  You need to resolve the ambiguity somehow:

- If you are using GHC or GHCi directly

  - either use a `-hide-package <package>` flag on the command line to hide one of the packages, or
  - hide the package by default using `ghc-pkg hide <package>`.  You may need to use `ghc-pkg --user hide <package>` if the package was installed in your home directory (the default on some platforms).
- You can use Cabal, and say exactly which one of the conflicting packages you depend on using the `build-depends` field in your `.cabal` file

Comment: An addendum: Cabal takes care of itself, so using `ghc-pkg hide` won't affect it. In other words, you won't break `cabal install` that way, which worried me the first time I saw the "just hide the package" advice. By the way--it's great to have you with us on SO, Simon!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem recently, and it was suggested that I run [`ghc-pkg hide {x}`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html#using-packages) where '{x}' is the name of one of those packages. It worked in my situation.