# Haskell Could not find module `System'

Tags: haskell

I'm new with Haskell and have trouble with its package.

I want to import System.Random but

> Could not find module `System.Random'

Then I tried to import System but

> Could not find module `System'.
>
> It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.0'.

---

I tried to search this problem, but those solutions still don't work.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604715/could-not-find-module-system-console-readline-in-haskell) said, I tried to install cabal on my Mac OS X using MacPort, but

> Error: The following dependencies were not installed: ghc
> Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.

I have installed [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) and can use ghci in command-line.
GHCi, version 7.2.1

---

Then I tried to use `ghc-pkg expose haskell98-2.0.0.0` as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476088/could-not-find-module-control-monad-reader) says.

But this time, I can't even run ghci.

> Top level:
>
> Ambiguous interface for `Prelude':
>
> it was found in multiple packages: base haskell98-2.0.0.0

---

So, what can I do without using cabal?

Comment: The Haskell Platform should come with Cabal. You shouldn't need to install anything else (other than the random package -- `cabal install random`)

Comment: According to the page you linked, Haskell Platform based on GHC 7.2.x has not been released yet.  You are asking for troubles if you have replaced GHC in Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`System.Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html) module belongs to [the `random` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random), which is [no longer included with GHC as of version 7.2.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html#id569450).

I'm not sure what to do about your Cabal problem, as I'm not familiar with Mac OS X, but I'd recommend getting that to work first. Installing `random` should then be trivial using Cabal.

As a possible workaround, you might want to consider using an older version of GHC.

Comment: but the `Random` module still exists

Comment: @user102008 Then how can I use it? `import Random` also doesn't work.

Comment: @Ovilia: `Random` belongs to the `haskell98` package, but [this package can no longer be used together with `base` as of GHC 7.2.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html#id569061).

Comment: @hammar It finally worked when I use an old version of GHC, thx.

Comment: @Olivia don't resort to old version of GHC, just don't use haskell98

Answer (score 18):

the cabal incantation:

```
cabal install random
```

Comment: won't this be a global install and should be discouraged? instead the dependencies should be added to the .cabal file?

Comment: yeah, you're right. You could use a cabal sandbox these days.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256908/371082) is a little bit dated and would lead to a global install and should be discouraged.

A better approach will be to add the random [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) as dependency in the `.cabal` file.

Something like this:

```
build-depends:       base ^>=4.13.0.0 --base package
                   , random           -- random package where System.Random can be found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cabal repl -b random # -b is short for --build-depends
```

This answer was based on another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203403/cant-install-system-random-by-cabal) thread here. Basically it installs the package `random` as a dependency of your project rather than installing it globally. Packages are installed globally if you just write `cabal install random` - which we dont usally want.