# I can t import Data.Matrix

Tags: haskell

I am trying to import Data.Matrix and I am getting this error:

Could not find module `Data.Matrix'
    Perhaps you meant Data.Ratio (from base-4.12.0.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
10 | import Data.Matrix

I don't know if I should install it or something like this and if I should do it, then how?

Comment: You probably need to install `matrix`, so `cabal install matrix`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell Could not find module \`System'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265550/haskell-could-not-find-module-system)